# Remote Queued Logging of Issues (not exceptions)

Tags: ios

We're writing an application which uses our http api, and occasionally it will encounter errors, failed connections, timeouts, etc.

We'd like to, at least in beta, be able to capture these incidents, and forward them to ourselves somehow. Since obviously many of these issues could be due to the actual connection being down, this would need to queue these incidents and send them when a connection is available.

I tried googling for an answer for this but to no avail, came across a bunch of solutions which catch exceptions, but not just random "incidents" (could really just be a string we log somewhere, we'd just include all the details in it).

Short of writing my own coredata (or something) backed queue, I'm at a loss at what a solution for this could be.

Does anyone know of any libs/services which could help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/), or less general purpose, [Parse](https://parse.com/). Not quite sure, but maybe [HockeyKit](http://hockeykit.net/) offers a solution for this, too.

Comment: HockeyKit looks interesting from our Enterprise distribution angle, but it doesn't look like it does arbitrary logging. Thanks for the suggestion to look into it.

Comment: @piotrb: I feared so after skimming their website (tbh, I never used it myself but thought that it was worth a shot mentioning).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Bugfender, it's a product we have built to solve this problem. We have found that while developing an app there are a lot of issues that are not crashes, so we decided to make our own product to help us on this.

It's easy to integrate and you can get the devices logs. Our service works offline and online, we have spent a lot of time to make it reliable and easy to use.

Compared to other products, you don't need any crash to get the logs, you choose when you want them.